# Navbar links are visible but not clickable

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have created a mobile and tablet version for my navbar(which gets activated when you click on the hamburger) and on the desktop resolution, I want the navbar to be visible immediately. And I have done so far... but the navbar links are not clickable on the desktop version. The reason for that is because on the HTML part I added *onClick* action on the hamburger for the menu but on the desktop resolution I just make *display: none* for the hamburger menu so the user never actually activates the hamburger for the navbar links to become clickable.

So this is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu">
         <li class="menu-item"><a href="/index.html" class="active">Home Page</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item"><a href="/content.html" class="nav-link">Content</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item"><a href="/store.html" class="nav-link">Products</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <div class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
          </div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
#check {
    display: none;
}

#menu{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#menu li{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

#menu.active{
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 100;
}
```

And this is what I did for the desktop resolution:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #menu{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        justify-content: space-between;
        font-weight: normal;
        height: 100px;
        width: 40%;
        align-items: center;
        right: 100px;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style:none;
        opacity: 100%;
    }
    
    #menu li{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        text-align: center;
        z-index:9999999;
    }
```

I don't know how to fix this without breaking my code for mobile and tablet resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Pointer events or comment it

```
#menu{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'onclick' instead of 'onClick'.

You should use this because Javascript is case sensetive.